# How to custom xls export order in WooCommerce

Tags: excel, wordpress, woocommerce, export, xls

I'm using Woocomerce plugin on Wordpress to export my orders. I've no problem to obtain a tab with the data I want (thanks to "Advanced Orders Export For WooCommerce " plugin) (see the pictures), but I wanna custom this by adding a header, above the table, with the logo and the description of my company.

How can I add a custom header (the same for each xls generated).

Thanks

[image: Excel tab]

Answer (score 0):

You should try this filter

```
add_action ( 'woe_xls_print_header', function($objPHPExcel, $formatter) {
   // use $objPHPExcel to add extra rows
},10,2);
```